# Adding MVC Menu control in my ASP.net Web Forms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have 2 sets of projects. One project is my main ASP.net webforms project, another project is my ASP.net MVC project. In my ASP.net MVC project I have built a navigation menu that works well in ASP.net MVC project. Now I want to use this navigation menu in my ASP.net web forms project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

mvc doesn't have special controls like asp.net server side controls

so your menu is basically is html and css with some ul,li,a tags so you can just copy and paste it into your asp.net webforms project

Comment: is there step by step guide of how to transfer or use my code from mvc to webforms

Comment: ready my answer again i said you only have to copy your html menu and paste it into your project this simple

Comment: The menu is not HTML its dynamically populated in MVC

Comment: so add your Code And Let Us See What To Do